# Should I assign object properties when initializing or after initializing?

Tags: c#

I have an object `obj1` with 11 properties.
Is it better to do this

```
Obj obj1 = new Obj()
{
 prop1 = int.Parse(data.Rows[0]["RequestId"].ToString())
 prop2 = IsBoss = (bool)data.Rows[0]["IsBoss"]
///etc...
}
```

or should I do

```
{
 Obj obj1 = new Obj(){}
 obj1.prop1 = int.Parse(data.Rows[0]["RequestId"].ToString())
 obj1.prop2 = IsBoss = (bool)data.Rows[0]["IsBoss"]
///etc...
}
```

Also as a  side question, when my data rows are null, an exception "Input string was not in a correct format" gets thrown because the field from the database is null. Typically the data wouldnt be null but would it be best to use a ternary operator to check if null or should i do a case in the sql qry.

Comment: I think it depends on people's opinion. The first way of setting property values along with initialization is better when the values to be set are straight forward. When it involves casting/calculations it's the second way. What values will you assign in SQL query for null? I think it's better to add null checks in C# than assigning any default values in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other answers, how you instantiate an object is up to you. Personally, I used to instantiate them and assign the properties all in one statement. The issue that I kept running into is when a had a property that failed to make it back from the database (like your `null exception` scenario), the the exception wouldn't give me an accurate line number. For that reason, I've moved to instantiating the object, then assigning the properties. This way, you'll know exactly which line/property is causing the issue.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.PropertyOne = "";
obj.PropertyTwo = "";
//etc...
```

As far as your second question goes, I handle `nulls` by using a ternary in combination with the `IsDBNull()` method on the `DataTableReader`.

```
 MyClass obj = new MyClass();
 obj.PropertyOne = rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("RequestId")) ? 0 
                      : rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("RequestId"));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I actually ended up instantiating first then assigning for the same reason you did, but never actually implemented a null check, the null was coming from a "test" row i inserted but the data should never have a null value.

Comment: @boo No problem. Even if it "should never" have a null, it's best to always check.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer setting object properties on initialization as per the first example, I think the code looks cleaner and better contained, but that is more of a personal preference.

For your second question when data is null coming back from the database you've got a few options.

```
{
    var obj1 = new Obj()
    {
        prop1 = int.TryParse(data.Rows[0]["RequestId"]?.ToString(), out int val) ? val : -1,
        prop2 = IsBoss = bool.TryParse(data.Rows[0]["IsBoss"].ToString(), out bool isBoss) ? isBoss : false
    }
}
```

Haven't tested but something like that should work, but it's not clean. I'd separate out the parsing into its own method or block. To help the code breathe a little.

Something like this:

```
{
   if(!(int.TryParse(data.Rows[0]["RequestId"]?.ToString(), out int requestId)))
    {
        requestId = -1;
    }

    bool.TryParse(data.Rows[0]["IsBoss"]?.ToString(), out IsBoss);

    var obj1 = new Obj()
    {
        prop1 = requestId,
        prop2 = IsBoss
    }
}
```